# On Linux, what is the correct way to completely empty a directory without deleting it?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, filesystems

Obvious solutions such as `rm -rf directory/*` will forget hidden files, for example. What is the correct way to do this?

My use case is the following: my directory is a subfolder of a root controlled directory, created by root and chowned to my user. If I delete it, I won't have the permissions to re-create it. However I want to make sure it's completely clean at the start of my process.

Comment: Before you downvote or vote to close my question, please be polite and leave a comment explaining your action. Thank you.

Comment: (I'm not a downvoter) The requests to close are quite clear: your question is not about programming but about Linux system administration; the close reason is _Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about)._ Though I'm not going to downvote or flag to close your question I do agree with the downvotes and close reason!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf : just because the shell can be used interactively doesn't mean it's not a programming language. My question makes little sense in the context of interactive use, and I know I will get better answers here than at SuperUser. Anyways, thanks for you comment!

Comment: I know it's a programming language; actually have a look at my profile and you'll see that most of my activity here is about Bash. Yet, your question can be understood as pure administration task, and not at all as a programming task; and I do respect (and understand, and even support) this point of view!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
find directory -mindepth 1 -delete
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
shopt -s dotglob
rm -rf directory/*
```

This will delete hidden files also (starting with a dot).

Or else use `find -delete`:

```
cd directory
find . -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
rm -rf /some/path/.* deletes all hidden files in that dir
```

Comment: `rm -rf` with a parameter list that includes `/some/path/.` and `/some/path/..` might not be a terribly healthy idea.